# How can I get all the objects connected to a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have to drop a table and to create a view with the same fields and name.
How can I get previously all the objects (tables, triggers, procedure, ...) connected to the original table so as to eventually or recompiling either modifying them?

Oracle version 11g

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run such a query; currently, I'm connected as a privileged user who is capable of querying `DBA_DEPENDENCIES`.

```
SQL> SELECT owner, name, type
  2    FROM dba_dependencies
  3   WHERE     1 = 1
  4         AND referenced_owner = 'SCOTT'
  5         AND referenced_type = 'TABLE'
  6         AND referenced_name = 'EMP';

OWNER                          NAME                           TYPE
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------
SCOTT                          TRG_BIU_EMP                    TRIGGER
MIKE                           PKG_EMPLOYEE                   PACKAGE BODY

SQL>
```

It says that `emp` table, owned by `scott`, is referenced by two other objects:

- trigger named `trg_biu_emp` owned by `scott`
- package body named `pkg_employee` owned by `mike`

---

You can also go with `all_dependencies` and `user_dependencies` (pay attention to their description! `owner` column is missing in `user_` views), but you'll get fewer and fewer results because both of them contain **less** information than `dba_dependencies`.

Therefore, if you don't want to miss something, look everywhere (i.e. `dba_` views). If you don't have required privileges, talk to your DBA.

Also, note that such a query won't *discover* possible references to that object elsewhere, such as front-end applications developed in e.g. Oracle Forms and Reports or Apex or ...